# ExpandableListView checking multiple items

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-checkbox

I am working with an ExpandableListView, populated from a database. A column in the database helps to determine which items have a CheckBox checked. Clicking on the CheckBox updates the database row for the item, initializing that variable. However, I am having trouble with scrolling and the list retaining its proper order and CheckBox selection.

This is my original attempt. It worked to a degree, in that I could get the list to populate correctly, but checkbox's wouldn't remain checked when clicked.

```
   @Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);
    }
        //convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, parent, false);

        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
        tv.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        checkBox.setFocusable(false);

        final int favorite = Integer.parseInt(getGroupFavorite(groupPosition).toString());
        if (favorite == 1)
        {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (!((CheckBox) view).isChecked())
                {
                    // Log.v("checkBox", "checked, setting to unChecked");

                    myDB.updateFavorite(favoriteHelperList[groupPosition], "0");
                }

                // has been set from checked to unchecked
                else
                {
                    // Log.v("checkBox", "unChecked, setting to Checked");

                    myDB.updateFavorite(favoriteHelperList[groupPosition], "1");
                    // Log.v("database", "database updated");
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

    return convertView;
}
```

After come digging I found several mentions of a ViewHolder, and have been experimenting with that, but to no avail.

```
    @Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolderGroup viewHolderGroup;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, parent, false);

        viewHolderGroup = new ViewHolderGroup();
        viewHolderGroup.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        viewHolderGroup.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favorite);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolderGroup);
    }

    else {
        viewHolderGroup = (ViewHolderGroup) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolderGroup.favorite = Integer.parseInt(getGroupFavorite(groupPosition).toString());
    viewHolderGroup.textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
    viewHolderGroup.checkBox.setFocusable(false);

    if(viewHolderGroup.favorite == 1) {
        viewHolderGroup.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }

    if (viewHolderGroup.textView != null) {
        viewHolderGroup.textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        viewHolderGroup.textView.setTag(getGroupId(groupPosition));
    }
return convertView;
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong, and how do I fix it? Being to have the list populate once, and for the button to update properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

some Days before I was having the same problem I have solved it by using this piece of code which is written by me...

```
explistView.ChildClick += (object pobjSender, ExpandableListView.ChildClickEventArgs    childArgs) => 
        {

            if(childstyle [listGroup [childArgs.GroupPosition]]   [childArgs.ChildPosition].checkedStatus){
                childstyle [listGroup[childArgs.GroupPosition]][childArgs.ChildPosition].checkedStatus=false;
                selectedServices.Remove(childstyle [listGroup[childArgs.GroupPosition]][childArgs.ChildPosition]);

            } else{
                childstyle[listGroup[childArgs.GroupPosition]][childArgs.ChildPosition].checkedStatus=true;
                //if(selectedServices.Contains(childstyle[listGroup[childArgs.GroupPosition]][childArgs.ChildPosition])){
                if (!selectedServices.Exists(x => x.ServiceID==childstyle[listGroup[childArgs.GroupPosition]][childArgs.ChildPosition].ServiceID)){
                    selectedServices.Add(childstyle[listGroup[childArgs.GroupPosition]][childArgs.ChildPosition]);
                }

            }
            expListAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        };


    }
```

childstyle is my dictionary object.
Hope you can understand it. it is quite complex.